# How to test SharePoint 2010 Web Services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

Is there a way to test sharepoint 2010 web services methods? Either using browser and modify the url or some kind of free tool to test web services. SharePoint web services looks like http://intranet.site.com/_vti_bin/webs.asmx. Some methods does not take parameter and others do.

Just want to be able to test methods using tool or if browsers allows it.

Comment: This tools seems to be light weight and serves the purpose. http://xyrow.com/Home/Free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tools http://www.xyrow.com/Home/Free seems to be light weight and serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Storm is worth a go - open source so you can be less worried about downloading nasties

http://storm.codeplex.com/